# Bootstrap modal not closing second time from JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have following code in a Partial View in an MVC project:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.AanwezigheidChauffeurID)").change(function () {
        setModalBody("busy", "Even geduld, de gegevens worden opgehaald...");
        $("#modalDialog").modal({ keyboard: false, backdrop: "static" });

        var chauffeurRequest = $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAanwezigheid", "Invoer")',
            data: { id: $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.AanwezigheidChauffeurID)").val() },
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST"
        });

        chauffeurRequest.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#entriesDiv").empty();
            $("#entriesDiv").append(data);
            $(".hoursInput:first").trigger("change");
            $("#modalDialog").modal("hide");
        });

        chauffeurRequest.fail(function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            setModalBody("error");
        });           
    });
});
```

This is the markup of the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalDialogLabel">Xwift</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close closeModalButton" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Sluiten">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="modal-dialog-body" class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="closeModalButton" disabled class="btn btn-primary closeModalButton" data-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The situation:

`$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.AanwezigheidChauffeurID)")` is referring to a *select* element. When I change the value of the drop-down, the AJAX request is launched and the modal dialog is shown. When the request is done, the modal is closed by calling `$("#modalDialog").modal("hide");`.

Now when I change the value of the drop-down again, the request is launched again and the modal is shown again. When the request is done, I can see the changes in the DOM through the backdrop from the modal, but the modal won't close anymore. When I call the line `$("#modalDialog").modal("hide");` in the console to test it, the modal does close.

Is there some reason why it won't close the second, third or more time?

Comment: If you are loading the modal using ajax, the element you first attached the handler to no longer exists. You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the modal is loaded/shown before the AJAX request is created. I have used this exact same technique before (Bootstrap 3 at the time) and this worked perfectly before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too bad I already asked this question before finding following question here on StackOverflow: [Bootstrap 4 Modal Not Closing Properly On Hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631374/bootstrap-4-modal-not-closing-properly-on-hide?rq=1)

Several comments and answers refer to the fact that the `fade` class disrupts the whole hiding of the modal. I have tried removing this class and it worked for me as well. Sadly, I didn't find a reason for this.